# Query to return all results of a GROUP BY in an array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple BigQuery query:

```
SELECT GroupingColumn, ... FROM Table GROUP BY GroupingColumn
```

is there any way to return ALL the columns for records matching the GroupingColumn in a nested array?

```
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| GroupingColumn1 | ARRAY of objects containing all the columns    |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Column1val      | [ { Column2, Column3 }, { Column2, Column3 } ] |
| Column1val      | ...                                            |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ARRAY_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators):

```
SELECT GroupingColumn, ARRAY_AGG(...)
FROM Table GROUP BY GroupingColumn
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me. By any chance, do you know how to sort the data in the array?